# Fedora 27 MacBook 12” 2015 Keyboard and Trackpad Driver

Tags: drivers, fedora

I have recently setup my computer to run both Fedora 27 and Mac OS, on different partitions. I was successful during installation, and the WiFi driver (brcmfmac) worked out of the box. However, I cannot manage to get Fedora to respond to any keyboard, or touch pad events on my laptop, only those from an external USB keyboard and mouse. Strangely enough, only the power button works on the laptop keyboard.

I have spent the last ~4 hours attempting to get this working, and I will outline my approaches below. I would very much appreciate any assistance in this area, as I am stuck on what to do next.

I believe that it is important to note that in my `/proc/bus/input` file, the operating system appears to "see" the touchpad and native keyboard (I am using a Magic Keyboard via USB and Sensei USB gaming mouse currently, but wish to use the native laptop keyboard and mouse):

```
N: Name="SteelSeries Sensei Raw Gaming Mouse"
P: Phys=usb-0000:00:14.0-1.1.2/input3
S: Sysfs=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.1/1-1.1.2/1-1.1.2:1.3/0003:1038:1369.0004/input/input7
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=kbd event7
B: PROP=0
B: EV=1f
B: KEY=3f0003007f 0 0 483ffff17aff32d bf54444600000000 1 130f938b17c000 677bfad9415fed 9ed68000004400 10000002
B: REL=40
B: ABS=100000000
B: MSC=10

I: Bus=0003 Vendor=05ac Product=0267 Version=0110
N: Name="Apple Inc. Magic Keyboard"
P: Phys=usb-0000:00:14.0-1.1.4/input1
S: Sysfs=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.1/1-1.1.4/1-1.1.4:1.1/0003:05AC:0267.0006/input/input8
U: Uniq=F0T54830AQ6G9KPAX
H: Handlers=sysrq kbd leds event8
B: PROP=0
B: EV=120013
B: KEY=10000 0 0 0 1007b00011007 ff9f217ac14057ff ffbeffdfffefffff fffffffffffffffe
B: MSC=10
B: LED=1f

I: Bus=001c Vendor=0000 Product=0000 Version=0000
N: Name="Apple SPI Keyboard"
P: Phys=applespi/input0
S: Sysfs=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:15.4/pxa2xx-spi.0/spi_master/spi0/spi-APP000D:00/input/input9
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=sysrq kbd leds event9
B: PROP=0
B: EV=120003
B: KEY=10000 0 0 0 6300001000 3800000000 710effd063c0001f ff7ffffffffffffe
B: LED=2

I: Bus=001c Vendor=0000 Product=0000 Version=0000
N: Name="Apple SPI Touchpad"
P: Phys=applespi/input1
S: Sysfs=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:15.4/pxa2xx-spi.0/spi_master/spi0/spi-APP000D:00/input/input10
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=mouse1 event10
B: PROP=5
B: EV=f
B: KEY=e520 10000 0 0 0 0
B: REL=3
B: ABS=27f800000000003
```

**Approach 1 - applespi/0.1**

When reading on some online tutorials, many individuals recommended this library called "applespi", in this [GitHub Repository](https://github.com/cb22/macbook12-spi-driver). To my knowledge, this installation was successful, because when I perform `dkms install -m applespi -v 0.1`, I get the following output: `Module applespi/0.1 already installed on kernel 4.15.8-300.fc27.x86_64/x86_64`. Additionally, in my `/proc/bus/input` file, the native keyboard and mouse is recognized in the physical location "applespi/input1" and "applespi/input0", leading me to believe this was successful.

I have a feeling this is the correct way to accomplish this problem, yet it still does not fix the problem, and the keyboard/touch pad are still unresponsive.

**Approach 2 - Pommed**

I also tried to use the Pommed library, meant for Debian/Ubuntu with little success. The package is located [here](https://packages.debian.org/sid/utils/pommed), but I was unable to install it. I then tried to build [pommed-light](https://github.com/bytbox/pommed-light) from source, with little avail.

I do not believe this is the correct way to solve this problem.

**Conclusion**

I have outlined two methods I attempted to solve the problem, and had little success with them both. I was unable to find many online resources to help me with this problem, as many others seemed to have their native mac keyboard/touch pad work right off the bat.

I would appreciate any suggestions, and am willing to update this thread with additional information if needed. Any help would be much appreciated! Thanks!